# Object initialization in the constructor (php 5.5)

Tags: php

> *Update*: the problem is related to compilation, if I compile with disable-all then the code works as expected. Strangely, only post 5.3 versions are affected. I will recompile the latest version a number of time, adding just one --enable-* at a time to find out what causes the problem and then will post the result.

I'm trying to migrate to php 5.5 and can't find a way round the simple thing, discribed many times but in different context.

I'm getting

> "Warning: Creating default object from empty value"

and I know that the workaround is to use stdObject, but it just doesn't work for me. Looks like I made a mistake somewhere, please help me.

I made a following code:

```
class MyClass {
   public $param;
   public function MyClass() {
      $this->param = "Param initialized";
   }
}
$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->param."\n";
```

It gives me an empty line. I tried to add `$this = new stdClass();` before param initialization, but it just hides the warning, "param" is still uninitialized.

I also tried to define constructor as `__construct` which gives absolutely the same result.

All I need is a simple example of object constructor which would initialize any attribute of the object being initialized.

Any ideas?

*Update*:
Guys, this is the real code. First, desirable behavior with 5.3:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat tc.php
<?
    class MyClass {
        public $param;
        public function MyClass() {
          echo "in Constructor\n";
          $this->param = "Param initialized";
        }
        public function getParam() {
          echo "in getParam\n";
          return $this->param;
        }
    }
    $myClass = new MyClass();
    echo "1: ".$myClass->param."\n";
    echo "2: ".$myClass->getParam()."\n";
    ?>
-bash-4.1$ ../php-5.3.29/sapi/cli/php tc.php
 in Constructor
 1: Param initialized
 in getParam
 2: Param initialized
 -bash-4.1$
```

Now same code with 5.5 (same with 5.6):

```
 -bash-4.1$ ../php-5.5.30/sapi/cli/php tc.php
  in Constructor
  Warning: Creating default object from empty value in tc.php on line 9
  1:
  in getParam
  2:
```

Now code corrected to avoid warning:

```
-bash-4.1$ cat /export/home/csweb/CS/Activiti-Decta/CScripter/tc.php
 <?
  class MyClass {
     public $param;
     public function MyClass() {
       echo "in Constructor\n";
       $this = new stdClass();
       $this->param = "Param initialized";
     }
     public function getParam() {
       echo "in getParam\n";
       return $this->param;
     }
  }
  $myClass = new MyClass();
  echo "1: ".$myClass->param."\n";
  echo "2: ".$myClass->getParam()."\n";
  ?>
-bash-4.1$ ../php-5.5.30/sapi/cli/php tc.php
 in Constructor
 1:
 in getParam
 2:
```

And for sake of completance php 5.6

```
-bash-4.1$ ../php-5.6.14/bin/php tc.php
 in Constructor
 1:
 in getParam
 2:
```

Any suggestion how to get same results as in 5.3 with 5.5 or 5.6?

Comment: [**norepro**](https://3v4l.org/9rbuD)

Comment: What are you talking about? This should work fine in PHP 5.5. You'll only get a deprecated notice in PHP 7 because you're using your constructors name as your classname.

Comment: I know it sounds mad, and it's making me mad, but I spent lot of time with this and still don't any idea what's going on :(

php -version
PHP 5.5.30 (cli)

Comment: @AlexDude We can't reproduce your problem. So make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code, so we can reproduce it

Comment: Which line is giving you that error?  Is it `$this->param = ...`?  Is there any other code besides this?  Because PHP 5.5.21-1~dotdeb.1 (cli) runs it just fine.  I want to figure this out too...  What if you delete and re-type this?

Comment: I updated the question with all the details. The code is real and working as shown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by wrong EXTRA_CFLAGS passed during the php compilation. Here is the one which worked:

```
export CPPFLAGS="-m64"; 
export EXTRA_CFLAGS="-m64";
make clean;
./configure --disable-all --disable-cgi --with-openssl --enable-json --with-oci8=instantclient,instantclient64_12_1/
make
```

And the one which produced php binary with such a strange behavior:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS="-D_XPG4_2 -D__lint -m64 -DSIOCGIFNAME"
```

Why so many things were added to CFLAGS? Because I tried to complie with --with-sockets, which produced compilation errors, so I was trying to show gcc the way around. PHP compiled successfully and make tests shown no signs of problems.

Don't have a time or desire to continue digging, I'm happy now as system smoothly running on 5.6

Comment: You may want to look at the remi php repo. I used to compile php manually but found it to be more hassle than it's worth. The remi repo is actively maintained and makes deploying new servers much simpler.